# Kernel version not updating after distribution upgrade (5.19.0-32 to 5.19.0-46)

Tags: command-line, upgrade, kernel, updates, 22.04

I performed an distribution upgrade using `update-manager`, which reported success.

However `uname -a` is still showing the previous kernel version:

```
5.19.0-32-generic
```

Where `history.log` in `/var/log/dist-upgrade` shows:

```
linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic
```

I closed all terminal windows and reopened to no effect.

Comment: Did you reboot your machine?

Comment: @ubfan1 Considered it, but was hoping that wasn't necessary.

Comment: The reboot is necessary to switch kernel versions.  You can look at /boot/grub/grub.cfg and see that the new kernel is the default before doing that if you want. Livepatching only applies to security patches, not kernel switches.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and accept it, maybe after a few days, helping others and gaining some reputation in the process.

Comment: You answered it, so go ahead and I'll accept... wu wei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating the kernel version, a reboot is necessary to switch which kernel version is running. You can look at /boot/grub/grub.cfg and see that the new kernel is the default before rebooting if you want. Livepatching only applies to security patches, not kernel switches

Answer (score 1):

download the appropriate kernel files for your architecture. For 64-bit architecture, you should download these files:

```
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-modules-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
```

go into the directory where you’ve downloaded the kernel and enter the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Ensure there isn’t any other “.deb” file in that directory other than downloaded kernel files.

It will take some time. After installation is finished, you can list the kernel files and look at them using the following command:

```
ls -l
```

Now that you’ve successfully installed the new kernel in Ubuntu; it’s time to reboot the machine. Ubuntu, by default, boots into the newer kernel version.

related: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Comment: The kernel was updated as part of a distribution upgrade initiated by running `update-manager`, which takes care of config files that `apt` may miss. Not sure of any specific dependencies between a distribution upgrade and its bundled kernel. Reboot fixed.

Comment: @samus "*running update-manager, which takes care of config files that apt may miss*" That's a myth: `update-manager` uses aptdaemon under the hood, which in turn uses the same libapt. Also, kernel binary packages from the Ubuntu repositories don't have any config files anyway.

Comment: @user535733 `update-manager` detected a partial installation/upgrade. The `apt-get update/upgrade` I ran after a fresh install was interrupted by a wifi drop. Even though I re-ran them successfully, `update-manager` still detected a partial upgrade. Regardless, next time I'll still try `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @user535733 Not to discount what you state, b/c I don't know, however just becuase `apt` and `update-manager` use the same daemon and libraries doesn't mean that they have the same application-level logic (aside from cl/gui).

Comment: @samus well, the "application level logic" (the solver) is in libapt, not in update-manager nor apt/apt-get. That's deliberate so all applications return the same result. Also, "*detected a partial installation/upgrade*" is suspicious -- a "partial upgrade" is usually very bad news and strongly suggests a version conflict that apt cannot resolve.

Comment: @user535733 If they're both simply front-ends, then end results should be identical.

Comment: If the end results of apt and update-manager are NOT identical, and you can reproduce that in a test environment, then please report the bug. In this case, the problem described in your question above was caused simply by not rebooting. Everything you have raised after that seems unclear (and a bit confusing). If you really want to explore it, please open a new question.